# How do I tell Libre Office to stop transferring me to a footnote?

Tags: libreoffice

When editing a document rather than highlighing a word, libre office sends me to a previous footnote. All I need is a page number in the footnote and nothing else.

How do I tell Libre Office to stop transferring me to a footnote unless I specifically want to be there?

Comment: This is about LibreOffice, not Ubuntu or LibreOffice on Ubuntu in particular. Perhaps you should ask your question here: http://ask.libreoffice.org/

Comment: This is not off-topic.